# Messed up my .bash_profile remotely, can't ssh back in

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access

I'm using a GNU/Linux system remotely, via SSH.

I mistakenly added something into my `$HOME/.bash_profile` scriot which causes an error. (To be specific: I added an `exec foo` command instead of `. foo`, applied to another bash script without execution permissions, which results in an error.)

Now I can't seem to SSH, SCP or SFTP into my machine: bash, my login shell, tries to run the `exec foo` command, gets the error and throws me out! I don't have any other account I can access remotely.

Is there something I can do to restore access to the system?

Additional details:

- Most ports other than for SSH are unavailable since the machine is behind a firewall.
- It's a Devuan 3 ASCII (~= Debian 10 Beowulf) system.

Comment: Assuming this is your machine, so you know the root password, why not simply log in as root?

Comment: @jamesqf: That [should really not be possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it).

Comment: The OP says it's his machine, so I would think he has physical access to it.  If not, there surely must be a sysadmin or someone who can.  Though I would think that this question ought to occasion a bit of thought about whether not allowing root logins via ssh is really that bad an idea :-)

Comment: @jamesqf: I have physical access to the machine when I'm near it; now I'm remote.

Comment: Physical access is nice and all; but it requires...well...*physical* access. Travel there, climb the tower, defeat the dra- sorry, got a bit carried away there.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think it suggests that permitting root logins via ssh is a good idea, but it _might_ suggest that keeping an empty, backup, non-admin account that you can log into if you feck up your "main" account may be a good idea. Then you can `sudo` and do whatever you need to do to recover. This would have the same security as your "main" account, except that you have given an attacker an additional account to try breaking into, but given you'll be using keys I don't think this is a problem.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63741/can-i-ssh-into-my-account-without-invoking-profile#63766) you can use

```
ssh -t user@host bash --noprofile
```

in fact, as @JoL suggests, you don't even need the `--noprofile`, since when ssh executes bash as just another command, it's not considered a login shell. Running `ssh -t user@host bash` will only read the RC files; and running `ssh -t user@host bash --norc` will not read even those.

Comment: You don't need `--noprofile`. `ssh -t user@host bash` already doesn't read the profile. The reason is because the profile is only read for "interactive login shells", and by doing `ssh -t user@host bash` you have a login non-interactive shell invoking a non-login interactive shell, so neither reads it.

Comment: @JoL: Please go ahead and edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Seems like you beat me to it. However, you miswrote the option name as `--newprofile`. Also, "since when ssh executes bash as just another command, it's not considered a login shell" is slightly inaccurate. It's probably pedantic of me, but the `bash` that `ssh` executes *is* a login shell. It's the `bash` that `bash` executes that is not. The process hierarchy is `sshd -> bash (login non-interactive) -> bash (non-login interactive)`.

Answer (score 48):

Try to SSH and run `sh` instead of `bash`, e.g.

```
ssh user@host sh
```

Then rename (`mv`) or edit the broken file (`ex/vi`).

Comment: I +1'ed you, but it's more convenient to have bash then just plain sh, like @styrofoamfly suggests...

Comment: Given that you aren't really going to do anything except run an editor to fix `.bash_profile` one you are logged in, I don't see how it matters what shell features are available.

Comment: This might work, but you can't count on "sh" actually being a different shell. For example on this Ubuntu box, /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/dash.

Comment: @spuck `sh` might be the same binary as `bash`, but it will still change its behaviour when invoked as "sh" (including not reading Bash-specific files) for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 21):

Run `ssh -t host vi .bash_profile` (or the editor of you choice in place of `vi`) and fix your `.bash_profile`.

(The `-t` option may not be needed, depending on which editor you choose.)

If you know exactly what needs to be fixed, you may be able to fix it non-interactively. For example, something like

```
printf 's/exec foo/. foo/\nwq\n' ssh host ed .bash_profile
```

Comment: For beginners who don't know `vi`, `nano`, `nano-tiny` or `mcedit` are convenient choices. (These editors are not always installed, but it's worth a try.)

Answer (score 1):

If only `~/.bash_profile` is messed up, see the other answers for fixing it. The rest of this answer elaborates on fixing all (other) login scripts.

If you are unlucky enough that you have `echo Bad luck; exit 42` in the beginning of both your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, and you have `/bin/bash` as your login shell, and `ssh root@host` doesn't work either, then its unlikely that you are able to fix it remotely. That's because sshd will insist on running your login shell, and the first `/bin/bash` will read either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, and specifying `bash --norc --noprofile` is too late, because the `/bin/bash` run by sshd doesn't have these flags, no matter what you specify in the `ssh` command-line.

If you've messed up only `~/.bashrc`, then run this to fix it:

```
echo mv -f .bashrc .bashrc.mess | ssh host
```

If you've messed up only `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bash_login`, then run this to fix it:

```
ssh host 'mv -f .bash_profile .bash_profile.mess; mv -f .profile .profile.mess; mv -f .bash_login .bash_login.mess'
```

After the fix, you can do `ssh host` as usual, and clean up the login script files in your favorite editor or using scp, sftp or rsync to transfer files and editing them locally.

Comment: So, this will work, but you're over-complicating the explanation and eventually suggesting a slight variation on existing answers.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: My answer adds the following over existing answers: 1. What happens if all login scripts are broken? 2. A different fix is needed depending on which login script is broken. 3. Provides fix for a broken ~/.bashrc . All of this can be relevant for future users who find this question. If you have a way to provide all this additional information and explanation in a simpler way, please suggest an edit.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: 4. Not all users are comfortable running a text editor within an SSH session. This answer provides fixes avoiding that.

Comment: 1. I didn't ask about "all login scripts". 2. `bash --noprofile` should be ok., because... 3. When bash is a login shell it doesn't run rc files anyway. Finally, the bash run by sshd is just a command - you can choose the flags you like.

Comment: 1. StackExchange is not only for helping the OP, but also for helping anyone having a similar problem in the future, finding this question later. 2. `bash --noprofile` is a working fix only if `~/.bashrc` is not messed up. 3. Correct. Finally, `ssh -t host bash --noprofile` runs 2 instances of bash: sshd runs `/bin/bash -c 'bash --noprofile'`. Thus it won't work if `~/.bashrc` (sourced by the 1st bash) is messed up, no matter what flags are specified for the 2nd bash, which never gets run.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: I'm happy that you have many fixes to choose from, and I'm happy that with my answer I provided value for users who have other login scripts messed up, and/or who are not comfortable running a text editor within an SSH session.

Comment: Other answers already provide solutions for those cases, actually.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: I disagree with the opinion that other answers provide solutions for all those cases this answer provides a solution for. Examples (which I already mentioned several times, but I repeat it here for clarity): 2. A different fix is needed depending on which login script is broken. 3. Provides fix for a broken ~/.bashrc . 4. Not all users are comfortable running a text editor within an SSH session. This answer provides fixes avoiding that. (We can argue if `ed` in another answer is a viable solution for those users, I think it isn't.)