# after ssh connecting to ubuntu server, cannot do anything

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, prompt

I was working on a server I have access to for a school project, which I am not an admin of it, and everything was working fine until recently, when [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE4qh.png) suddenly began to happen after I logged in using the normal `ssh` command.  Now, every time that I log into the server, the above occurs and I cannot use any command or anything else; anything I type is written, but nothing happens, and the normal command line does not appear either (the `..... $` before you type something in normal ubuntu server).

Is this something I did or would anyone know why this happened and why I can't use any commands or do anything once I'm logged into the server anymore? I looked for this problem and I found nothing related to this (the problem is not with `ssh`, I am able to connect to the server, but once I'm in it, I can't do anything).

Since I am only a user of the server and not an admin, the solutions on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93692/no-prompt-after-successful-ssh-login) do not seem to work for me. I'm connecting from a windows machine.

Comment: It looks like a misconfigured shell config for your user (typo in the config, missing operator/delimiter, etc.)

Comment: @JW0914 okay, is it possible for me to fix it as a normal user, or is this only accessible by an admin of the server?

Comment: Please check [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1504530/432690). I'm not sure it will help because you're connecting from Windows. I tried to mark your question as a *possible* duplicate but I'm reputable enough in the [tag:linux] tag to single-handedly close the question and I don't really want to (at least not yet). Therefore this comment. How do you connect from Windows? Is it with some command line `ssh` client? Can you use commands provided by answers to the linked question?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I just use "ssh user@host". I checked your link and he has an error which makes sense on why it does not work. I tried logging it with "ssh user@host sh" which works, but it's not a terminal so I can't really do anything on it...

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not a terminal so I can't really do anything on it"?

Comment: When you use "ssh user@host sh", with the 'sh' at the end, you enter the server but do not log in with a terminal. You can't do much and can't use any commands doing this. It says "error something, not on a terminal". That's the normal behavior of sh, they used it to fix a bug he did, but i did not cause any bugs so I do not have to fix anything. I just don't know what to do...

Comment: @L-FBouchard Have you tried logging in from multiple SSH clients to see if this is potentially an issue on the client-side program's settings? _(I still think it looks like output from a misconfigured shell config, but the client should be ruled out.)_ If you're using OpenSSH on Windows and installed it via Settings' Add Features, please uninstall it, then install OpenSSH from Microsoft's [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) GitHub.  I would also try [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)

Comment: It used to work, now it doesn't. You need to fix *something*. If not you then the administrator(s). "Not on a terminal" is probably because there is no tty allocated. `ssh -t` requests tty allocation (and it appeared under the linked question!). For now it looks you have all means to at least *investigate* the problem. Can you reach Bash like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1504532/432690)? Can you run yet another shell? Does it complain about terminal? Do you know what shell is your default shell that doesn't work?

Comment: System load: 30 could also be a concern, if the system used to have a much smaller load before.